# ssl version and cipher suites of the client

Tags: ssl, go, https

I'm working on a soap server, that will serve some old embedded computers with an legacy soap protocol.

I write it in *go* and so far used just plain `http`, but in production it must use `ssl` encryption. So I've just created a key and a cert (from [this site](https://gist.github.com/denji/12b3a568f092ab951456)) and used the `http.ListenAndServeTLS` function.

But now the computers cannot connect and the server is just printing a handshake error:

`server.go:2848: http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:38790: tls: no cipher suite supported by both client and server`

In the docs, for the computers, isn't the supported ssl version or the ciphers. So I wanted to know, how to find out the client's ssl version, and also the available cipher suites that the client supports.

And then how can I configure the golang http server so it will support the selected ciphers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be two questions here, so let's do this in two parts:

#### Finding the client's TLS version and supported cipher suites:

To do this, you need to set the `GetConfigForClient` field of the [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) object.

This field takes a method with signature:

```
func(*ClientHelloInfo) (*Config, error)
```

It is called on receipt of a `Client Hello` message with a [ClientHelloInfo](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ClientHelloInfo) struct. This struct contains the following fields of interest to you:

```
    // CipherSuites lists the CipherSuites supported by the client (e.g.
    // TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA).
    CipherSuites []uint16

    // SupportedVersions lists the TLS versions supported by the client.
    // For TLS versions less than 1.3, this is extrapolated from the max
    // version advertised by the client, so values other than the greatest
    // might be rejected if used.
    SupportedVersions []uint16
```

Please read the comments around `GetConfigForClient` and `ClientHelloInfo` for exactly how `GetConfigForClient` should behave, and for field details.

#### Specifying server-supported version and cipher suites:

This is also done through the [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) object using the following fields:

```
    // CipherSuites is a list of supported cipher suites. If CipherSuites
    // is nil, TLS uses a list of suites supported by the implementation.
    CipherSuites []uint16

    // MinVersion contains the minimum SSL/TLS version that is acceptable.
    // If zero, then TLS 1.0 is taken as the minimum.
    MinVersion uint16

    // MaxVersion contains the maximum SSL/TLS version that is acceptable.
    // If zero, then the maximum version supported by this package is used,
    // which is currently TLS 1.2.
    MaxVersion uint16
```

For example, you could set your tls.Config with the following fields:

```
    CipherSuites: []uint16{
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
        etc...
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
    },

    MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
```

The full list of supported cipher suites is in the [tls docs](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#pkg-constants).

Comment: That's great, thaks. So I found out it supports:`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA`. Adding thede to the `CipherSuites` didn't help. I must create an `RSA` key/cert?

Comment: You do need a server certificate and key. These are usually with RSA for compatibility. If this is for a public-facing server, the easiest way is to use Let's Encrypt.

Comment: I've created the key using `openssl` (just copied the commands from [this](https://gist.github.com/denji/12b3a568f092ab951456) site). But just now I've finally understood that the second command (`openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -out server.key`) created `ECDSA` key, and not a `RSA` key. So I've created a new `RSA` key now it's all happily running thank you!

Comment: @microo8: those cipher suites look like SSL, elliptic curve diffie-hellman is more of a TLS thing. You definitely shouldn't be using SSL, and not even TLS 1.0.

Comment: In `SupportedVersions` is that it supports TLS1.0 so I think it is ok